# Namespace not updating after I alter my project folder in solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm recently working on my own project, just for practice designing, in that project I've create a folder called `User_control` that is where I pull all the `user control` `item` in it, some error was occur and I have to change `User_control` folder's name into `US control`, but when I did this the namespace of previous folder name are not changing to new name and that cause bunch of new error, I've rebuilt solution several time but its seem not to work.

Comment: And, what are the errors (we aren't very good at mind-reading from this distance)(?  If you change the folder structure below the folder in which the solution's SLN file is located, then the projects that the the solution reference may no longer be findable.  Depending on how much you have done, it may be easier to start over from scratch and copy paste your work in from your old solution.

Comment: the first one was `CS0436`,project make a self-reference so i deleted it, then changed the folder name. the follows was mainly `CS1503`, all the controls being missing in spite of they are there, in `US control` folder

Comment: Errors have messages associated with them.  None of us have those error codes memorized.  If you only have a foreign language text message, you can get the English  version from a simple internet search, for example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0436.  You might also want to explain what you mean by _"so i deleted it"_.  Finally, stuff like that belongs in your question (which you can edit), not in a comment

Comment: @Valkyrine, I am confused about your problem. As you said, you only changed Folder name, why is it related to your namespace? what is your initial namespace name?

Comment: A change in folder name does not automatically move classes in that folder to the new namespace. Which cannot have a space in it anyway. And if you have separate files for the "design" part and the "code" part of some control, you need to update the namespace in all locations (including where you refer to that namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Either use the find and replace function in Visual Studio (or whatever IDE you are using) to replace the old names are utilize the refactor next time.